# Excel 2010 Calculating Production line quantities without long calculations

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program:**  Excel 2010
**Requirements:** Prefer no VBA (Macro free book)

I am creating a spreadsheet to calculate items required for components (parts).  I have a list of the product, and under the number of specific parts.  I have a calculation which tells me what the total parts are needed, but, is there a better way?

```
=($C$32*C34)+($D$32*D34)+($E$32*E34)+($F$32*F34)+($G$32*G34)+($H$32*H34)+($I$32*I34)+($J$32*J34)+($K$32*K34)  

|       A       |   B   |     C      |      D      |       E         |    F    |
| Making:       |       |    2       |    2        |       2         |         |
|---------------|-------|------------|-------------|-----------------|---------|
| Item ->       | Total | Small raft | Rowing boat | Sm sailing boat | Corbita |  
|               |       |            |             |                 |         |
| Planks        | 20    | 4          | 6           |                 |         |
| Logs          | 8     | 4          |             |                 |         |
| Nails - Large | 16    | 8          |             |                 |         |
| Oars          |       |            |             |                 |         |
```

In the above, you can see that `($C$32*C34)` = 8  &  `($D$32*D34)` = 12  =>  12+8 = 20 (B34)  (Planks Total)

Is there an easier way of doing this, or will my equation just keep getting bigger?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `SumProduct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chris neilsen mentioned in his comment, you can use the [`SUMPRODUCT`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumproduct.php) function in Excel. The formula in your cell `B34` (total planks) should look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C32:K32,C34:K34)
```

This has the effect of multiplying the corresponding components in the given ranges (`C32 * C34`, `D32 * D34`, etc.) and then returning the sum of those products/multiplications.

As you add more columns, you can expand `K` to the last column in the range that you want to add up in both ranges.